# assign template to other pages

Tags: html, templates, joomla, joomla3.0

I am trying to assign my other templates to menus that I have created in the backend of my joomla project.

Should I create another templateDetails.xml for my other templates to display in the template manager?

Or am I missing any code to activate my other template to the template manager?

Here is my main page:

```html
<?php

    defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted Access' );

    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?'.'>';

    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();

    /* Let's tell Joomla! to use HTML5 */
    $doc->setHtml5(true);

?>

<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang=""> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

    <jdoc:include type="head" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/normalize.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/main.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/cognitif.css" type="text/css">

    <!-- <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script> -->

    <script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <div class="header-container">
                    <div class="red-box">
                        <div class="wrapper clearfix">
                            <div class="cols-2">
<!--                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                                </ul> -->
                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="redbox-menu" style="xhtml"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cols-2 nav-align-right">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="SEARCH"/></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">(02) 621 0631</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          <header class="wrapper clearfix">
              <div class="title"><div id="open-menu"></div><a href="#" id="site-title"><span class="hidden">h1.title</span></a></div>
              <nav>
<!--                   <ul>
                      <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">our businesses</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">investor relations</a></li>
                  </ul> -->
                  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="main-menu" style="xhtml"/>
              </nav>
          </header>
        </div>

        <div class="main-container no-aside">

            <article>
                <header style="background-image: url(<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/img/mainpage-banner.png)">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <h1>Let’s collaborate on <em>Making Possibilities</em></h1>
                        <div id="mainform" class="clearfix">
                            <div class="cols-4">
                                <label class="question-set">I am an 
                                    <select class="red-selection">
                                        <option>Owner</option>
                                        <option>Option2</option>
                                        <option>Option3</option>
                                        <option>Option4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </label>
                                
                                <input type="text" class="input-standard" placeholder="Looking for..." />
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="cols-4">
                                <label class="question-set">Organization Size
                                </label>
                                
                                <input type="text" class="input-standard" placeholder="1-5" />
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="cols-4">
                                <label class="question-set">Department
                                </label>
                                
                                <input type="text" class="input-standard" placeholder="Sales" />
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="cols-4">
                                <button class="button large-btn">Collaborate Now</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
            
                <div style="background: url(<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/img/bg-emblem.png) center 200px no-repeat;">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <section class="white-box box-arrow clearfix">
                            <div class="center-content">
                                <img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/img/cognitif-emblem.png">
                                <h2>Our promise, already a given</h2>
                                <!-- <p>Cras venenatis feugiat nibh quis tempus. Quisque libero nibh, consequat posuere, tempus pulvinar purus.</p> -->
                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="our-promise" style="xhtml"/>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="box-fader clearfix">
                                <div class="cols-4 details-box">
                                    <!-- <h3>Exceptional<br> business care</h3>
                                    <p>Cras venenatis feugiat nibh quis tempus. Quisque libero nibh, consequat posuere, tempus pulvinar purus.</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="button btn-outline">Learn More</a></p> -->
                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="business-care" style="xhtml"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cols-4 details-box">
                                  <!-- <h3>Reliable service<br> delivery</h3>
                                    <p>Cras venenatis feugiat nibh quis tempus. Quisque libero nibh, consequat posuere, tempus pulvinar purus.</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="button btn-outline">Learn More</a></p> -->
                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="reliable-service" style="xhtml"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cols-4 details-box">
                                    <!-- <h3>Realized gains<br> from productivity</h3>
                                    <p>Cras venenatis feugiat nibh quis tempus. Quisque libero nibh, consequat posuere, tempus pulvinar purus.</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="button btn-outline">Learn More</a></p> -->
                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="realized-gains" style="xhtml"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cols-4 last details-box">
                                    <!-- <h3>Perfect-fit<br> solutions</h3>
                                    <p>Cras venenatis feugiat nibh quis tempus. Quisque libero nibh, consequat posuere, tempus pulvinar purus.</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="button btn-outline">Learn More</a></p> -->
                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="perfect-solutions" style="xhtml"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                        
                        <section class="clearfix">
                            <div class="center-content">
                                <img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/img/array-ico.png">
                                <h2>Wide array of businesses</h2>
                                <!-- <p>Cras venenatis feugiat nibh quis tempus. Quisque libero nibh, consequat posuere, tempus pulvinar purus.</p> -->
                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="our-business" style="xhtml"/>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <div class="cols-4 details-box">
                                    <!-- <h3>Business<br> consulting</h3>
                                    <p>Cras venenatis feugiat nibh quis tempus. Quisque libero nibh, consequat posuere, tempus pulvinar purus.</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="button btn-outline">Learn More</a></p> -->
                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="business-consulting" style="xhtml"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cols-4 details-box">
                                    <!-- <h3>Knowledge process<br> outsourcing</h3>
                                    <p>Cras venenatis feugiat nibh quis tempus. Quisque libero nibh, consequat posuere, tempus pulvinar purus.</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="button btn-outline">Learn More</a></p> -->
                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="knowledge-process" style="xhtml"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cols-4 details-box">
                                    <!-- <h3>Executed<br> search</h3>
                                    <p>Cras venenatis feugiat nibh quis tempus. Quisque libero nibh, consequat posuere, tempus pulvinar purus.</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="button btn-outline">Learn More</a></p> -->
                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="executed-search" style="xhtml"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cols-4 details-box">
                                    <!-- <h3>Integrated business<br> solutions</h3>
                                    <p>Cras venenatis feugiat nibh quis tempus. Quisque libero nibh, consequat posuere, tempus pulvinar purus.</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="button btn-outline">Learn More</a></p> -->
                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="integrated-business" style="xhtml"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </section>
                                        
                        <section class="featured-section clearfix">
                            <div class="image-box cols-31" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/img/people.png)">
                                <div class="featured-content">
                                    <h2>Solutions to an ever changing market</h2>
                                    <!-- <p>Pellentesque quis massa ultricies, varius velit sodales, consectetur sem. Praesent at massa lorem. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="button btn-white-outline">Learn More</a></p> -->
                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="featured-content" style="xhtml"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="referal-box cols-33">
                                <h2>Join our Referral Program</h2>
                                <!-- <p>Pellentesque quis massa ultricies, varius velit sodales, consectetur sem. Praesent at</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="button btn-white-outline">Learn More</a></p> -->
                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="referral-box" style="xhtml"/>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                        
                        <section class="news-box-set clearfix">
                            <div class="news-box cols-4">
                                <div class="news-cat">News</div>
                                <h2><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h2>
                                <div class="news-info">2days ago by <a href="#">Cognitif</a></div>
                                <p>Pellentesque quis massa ultricies, varius velit sodales, consectetur sem. Praesent at </p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="button btn-outline">Read More</a></p>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="news-box cols-4">
                                <div class="news-cat">News</div>
                                <h2><a href="#">Sed cursus blandit rhoncus</a></h2>
                                <div class="news-info">2days ago by <a href="#">Cognitif</a></div>
                                <p>Pellentesque quis massa ultricies, varius velit sodales, consectetur sem. Praesent at </p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="button btn-outline">Read More</a></p>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="news-box cols-4 featured clearfix">
                                <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/img/woman.png)"></div>
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="news-cat">Featured</div>
                                    <h2><a href="#">Etiam et molestie turpis</a></h2>
                                    <div class="news-info">2days ago by <a href="#">Cognitif</a></div>
                                    <p>Pellentesque quis massa ultricies, varius velit sodales, consectetur sem. Praesent at </p>
                                    <p><a href="#" class="button btn-outline">Read More</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                        
                        <section class="clearfix">
                            <div class="center-content red-header">
                                <h2>Strong business relationships</h2>
                                <p>Nullam accumsan scelerisque leo, sed ultricies orci tristique non. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas eget velit id leo scelerisque molestie.</p>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                        
                        <footer class="contact-form clearfix" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/img/contact-bg.png)">
                            <div class="form-holder">
                                <h2>Together, we’ll do great.</h2>
                                <p> Cras venenatis feugiat nibh quis tempus. Quisque libero nibh, consequat posuere, tempus pulvinar purus.</p>
                                
                                <form class="rounded-input">
                                    <input type="text" class="rounded-input cols-4" placeholder="Your Name" />
                                    <input type="text" class="rounded-input cols-4" placeholder="Position" />
                                    <input type="text" class="rounded-input cols-4" placeholder="Company Name" />
                                    <input type="text" class="rounded-input cols-4" placeholder="Email Name" />
                                    
                                    <label class="center-content">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="rounded-input"/> I’m looking for the best solution with fantastic local support.
                                    </label>
                                    
                                    <button class="button">Get a Solution</button>
                                    
                                    <p><small>*Your privacy is very important to us. To learn more about our information processesing procedures, please visit our <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>.</small></p>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>

            <!--aside>
                <h3>aside</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sodales urna non odio egestas tempor. Nunc vel vehicula ante. Etiam bibendum iaculis libero, eget molestie nisl pharetra in. In semper consequat est, eu porta velit mollis nec. Curabitur posuere enim eget turpis feugiat tempor. Etiam ullamcorper lorem dapibus velit suscipit ultrices.</p>
            </aside-->

        </div> <!-- #main-container -->

        <div class="footer-container">
            <footer class="black-bg wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="cols-33">
                    <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/img/cognitif-white-transparent.png"></a>
                    <p>Unit 3010, One Corporate Center, Julia Vargas Street, corner Meralco Avenue, Ortigas Center, Pasig City, Metro Manila</p>
                    <p><a href="tel:026210631">(02) 621 0631</a></p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="cols-31 footer-navs clearfix">
                    <div class="cols-4">
                        <h4>Get in touch</h4>
                        
<!--                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Info</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Follow Us</a></li>
                        </ul> -->
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="getintouch-menu" style="xhtml"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cols-4">
                        <h4>Our company in a glance</h4>
                        
<!--                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Corporate governance</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">News and events</a></li>
                        </ul> -->
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="ourcompany-menu" style="xhtml"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cols-4">
                        <h4>Area of Expertise</h4>
                        
<!--                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">HR Solutions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Investments</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Outsourcings</a></li>
                        </ul> -->
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="aoe-menu" style="xhtml"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cols-4">
                        <h4>Area of Expertise</h4>
                        
<!--                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">HR Solutions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Investments</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Outsourcing</a></li>
                        </ul> -->
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="aoe-menu" style="xhtml"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
            
            <div class="center-content baseline">Copyright &copy; 2017 Cognitif. All rights reserved.</div>
            
        </div>
        
        <div id="mobile-menu">
            <div style="position: relative">
                <div id="close-menu">X</div>
                <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Search for..." />
<!--                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Investor Relations</a></li>
                </ul> -->
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mobile-menu" style="xhtml"/>
<!--                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">(02) 621 0631</a></li>
                </ul> -->
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="sub-menu" style="xhtml"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mobile-menu-closer"></div>

      <!--script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script-->
      <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

      <script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my code for my other page:

```html
<?php

    defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted Access' );

    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?'.'>';

    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();

    /* Let's tell Joomla! to use HTML5 */
    $doc->setHtml5(true);

?>

<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang=""> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

    <jdoc:include type="head" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/normalize.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/main.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/cognitif.css" type="text/css">

    <script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <div class="header-container">
            <div class="red-box">
                <div class="wrapper clearfix">
                    <div class="cols-2">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="redbox-menu" style="xhtml"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cols-2 nav-align-right">
                        <ul>
                            <li><input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="SEARCH"/></li>
                            <li><a href="#">(02) 621 0631</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <header class="wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="title"><div id="open-menu"></div><a href="#" id="site-title"><span class="hidden">h1.title</span></a></div>
                <nav>
                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="main-menu" style="xhtml"/>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>

        <div class="main-container page">

            <article>
                <header style="background-image: url(<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/img/about-header.jpg)">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <h1>About Us</h1>
                    </div>
                </header>
            </article>
            
            <article>
                <div class="page-content wrapper clearfix">
                    <section class="clearfix">
                        <div id="breadcrumb">
                            <?php JFactory::getApplication()->getPathWay(); ?> 
                        </div>
                        
                        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
                        <p>Vivamus vel varius velit, at sodales tortor. Suspendisse dignissim ac nisi in auctor. Mauris leo mauris, ultrices a purus id, sagittis rutrum felis. Vestibulum pretium, tellus vitae mattis mollis, nisi mauris ornare metus, vitae tempor nibh massa ac tellus. Nunc eu massa interdum, semper felis placerat, vestibulum diam. Mauris ut pulvinar nibh.</p>
                        <p>Maecenas molestie enim ut mollis tincidunt. Donec iaculis cursus malesuada. Suspendisse vitae tellus iaculis, rutrum ipsum molestie, auctor nunc. Fusce leo metus, dapibus ut enim quis, sodales luctus urna. Donec ultricies ac ex ac venenatis. Suspendisse eleifend finibus porttitor. Maecenas dictum dolor aliquet lorem elementum ultrices.</p>
                        <p>Integer iaculis auctor orci, ut faucibus augue. Nulla sagittis viverra scelerisque. Suspendisse lobortis metus sed mi vestibulum faucibus. Pellentesque congue elit ligula, vel pretium tortor rhoncus vitae. Aliquam quis orci nec ipsum commodo auctor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis </p>
                        <p>Praesent eget ipsum ac dui commodo ornare. Aliquam gravida ipsum nec ultrices fermentum. Aliquam in turpis sollicitudin, blandit turpis at, vestibulum lacus. Maecenas finibus ac neque sit amet luctus. Curabitur quis ipsum eget velit auctor fringilla.</p>
                        
                        <h3>Aenean molestie lacus a blandit</h3>
                        <p>Nunc ipsum tellus, viverra molestie leo ut Integer iaculis auctor orci, ut faucibus augue. Nulla sagittis viverra scelerisque. Suspendisse lobortis metus sed mi vestibulum faucibus. Pellentesque congue elit ligula, vel pretium tortor rhoncus vitae. Aliquam quis orci nec ipsum commodo auctor. Aliquam gravida ipsum nec ultrices fermentum. Aliquam in turpis sollicitudin, blandit turpis at, vestibulum lacus. </p>
                        <p>Maecenas finibus ac neque sit amet luctus. Curabitur quis ipsum eget velit auctor fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam vel vulputate sem. Aenean justo diam, feugiat sit amet dolor eget, maximus mollis velit.</p>
                        
                        <h3>Nunc accumsan varius ipsum, eu maximus</h3>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <div class="cols-2">
                                <img src="img/thumb-01.jpg">
                                <h4>Vivamus dictum augue arcu</h4>
                                <h5>Maecenas Etiam</h5>
                                <p>Integer iaculis auctor orci, ut faucibus augue. Nulla sagittis viverra scelerisque. Suspendisse lobortis metus sed mi vestibulum faucibus. Pellentesque congue elit ligula, vel pretium tortor rhoncus vitae. Aliquam quis orci nec ipsum commodo auctor. Aliquam gravida ipsum nec ultrices fermentum. Aliquam in turpis sollicitudin.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cols-2">
                                <img src="img/thumb-02.jpg">
                                <h4>Quisque ac velit congue</h4>
                                <h5>Aliquam Fusce</h5>
                                <p>Integer iaculis auctor orci, ut faucibus augue. Nulla sagittis viverra scelerisque. Suspendisse lobortis metus sed mi vestibulum faucibus. Pellentesque congue elit ligula, vel pretium tortor rhoncus vitae. Aliquam quis orci nec ipsum commodo auctor. Aliquam gravida ipsum nec ultrices fermentum. Aliquam in turpis sollicitudin.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    
                    <aside>
                        <input type="text" class="aside-search" placeholder="Search Topics..." />
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">News and Media</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Knowledge and Insights</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Awards and Recognition</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Corporate Governance</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sponsorship</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Notifications</a></li>
                            <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </aside>
                </div>
            </article>

        </div> <!-- #main-container -->

        <div class="footer-container">
            <footer class="black-bg wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="cols-33">
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/cognitif-white-transparent.png"></a>
                    <p>Unit 3010, One Corporate Center, Julia Vargas Street, corner Meralco Avenue, Ortigas Center, Pasig City, Metro Manila</p>
                    <p><a href="tel:026210631">(02) 621 0631</a></p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="cols-31 footer-navs clearfix">
                    <div class="cols-4">
                        <h4>Get in touch</h4>
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="getintouch-menu" style="xhtml"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cols-4">
                        <h4>Our company in a glance</h4>
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="ourcompany-menu" style="xhtml"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cols-4">
                        <h4>Area of Expertise</h4>
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="aoe-menu" style="xhtml"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cols-4">
                        <h4>Area of Expertise</h4>
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="aoe-menu" style="xhtml"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
            
            <div class="center-content baseline">Copyright &copy; 2017 Cognitif. All rights reserved.</div>
            
        </div>
        
        <div id="mobile-menu">
            <div style="position: relative">
                <div id="close-menu">X</div>
                <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Search for..." />

                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mobile-menu" style="xhtml"/>

                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="sub-menu" style="xhtml"/>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mobile-menu-closer"></div>

        <!--script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script-->
      <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

      <script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am suspecting that I have missing code that I need to put on my second page in order for the template manager to read my second template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe it sounds like your second template may not be correctly installed. If you don't see it under Extensions > Templates > Templates then you need to fix that first.

> I am wondering if should I create another templateDetails.xml ...

Yes, your second template would need this. The typical template has its own folder which would have at minimum index.php, templateDetails.xml, and usually css, js and image files.

If you think this is already in place, try Extensions > Manage > Discover then Discover. This may find a template which hasn't been correctly installed.

Once your second template is showing in the Extensions > Templates > Templates (formerly the Template Manager), you can assign menu items to the second template from Extensions > Templates > Styles.  From this screen select your second template then go to the Menu Assignment tab.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for explaining it elaborately. I've done what you suggested and it fixed my issue.

Comment: Thx @Terence, I'm pleased we fixed the problem and good luck with Joomla!